# Choosing the right design pattern for execution on a dictionary key

Tags: python, design-patterns, dictionary

Which design pattern is preferred?

For a dictionary d that may or may not have a key named 'foo'...

**Pattern A**

```
if d.get('foo'):
    func(d.get('foo'))
```

**Pattern B**

```
foo = d.get('foo')
if foo:
    func(foo)
```

I think I prefer the 2-line approach of Pattern A.  Does the second lookup cost more than the extra assignment of Pattern B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things you're writing do completely different things.

The first one uses the string `'foo'` as the argument to `func`.

The second one uses whatever value is in `d['foo']` as the argument to `func`.

Which one is right depends entirely on which one is what you actually want to do.

---

In your edited version, doing the lookup twice is silly.

Of course it "costs more"—you have to hash `'foo'` twice, and look up that hash value (and possibly probe a few times) twice, and that costs twice as much as doing it once. But that performance cost is unlikely to matter in any real program. (Even if your key were expensive to hash—which a three-character string is not—most types that are expensive to hash will cache the hash value the first time…)

A more realistic potential problem is that you've added a race condition for no good reason if you ever want to make your code multithreaded or just reentrant.

But, more importantly, repeating yourself always introduces opportunities for error, because you have to repeat yourself exactly right, and it's not always obvious when you haven't done so, especially if you later edit one of the copies. (The fact that you got the question wrong in the first place is a pretty good argument…) And for the same reasons, you also introduce opportunities for people to read your code wrong, or just stumble over reading it and have to think about something that should have been obvious. That's why DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself—unless you have a good reason to do so) is a fundamental principle in programming.

---

That being said, the first one would be much better written as `if 'foo' in d:`. If you don't actually need the value, don't retrieve it.

And the second one might be better written with EAFP instead of LBYL:

```
try:
    func(d['foo'])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Or, in Python 3.5:

```
func(d['foo']) except KeyError: None
```

Comment: I typed it in wrong.  I've updated per my original intention.

Comment: Yes.  Excellent example of why DRY is important.  Pattern A with the `in` operator sounds much better.